# Implementing PHP/Mysql Login System to Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, session

My friend has a wordpress site and wants me to add my premade PHP/Mysql login system. Currently i'm trying to insert PHP pages into the wordpress templates using this plugin: http://www.willmaster.com/software/WPplugins/.

The plugin lets me add php code to the page using this syntax:

`[insert_php]
include "account/login.php";
[/insert_php]`

However, doing this creates an issues with sessions as the page header is already sent by the wordpress page before the php file is included. I'm getting the following error:

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter – headers already sent (output started at ...)
Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at...`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: can you add ob_start at top of functions.php file and try to remove blank space at closing tag of php ?> no more blank space after this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the code for your login at the top in the theme's header.php or simply don't have session_start() in login.php. Or use session_status() to check if the session has started.

Answer (score 0):

You cant start a session after the head becuse data allready started to send to browser. You need to include your code in the head before any code

Comment: Do I need to edit the already provided wordpress template and put the code at the top?